# Print Winforms panel and gridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

New to printing and I have a form with 2 blocks. The first one is a panel with labels and textboxes arranged in 5 rows and 2 cols. Below this is a grid view that displays items. I like the present look of the form and would like to print it,as it is, just that the grid's list can go to second page too. Please tell me the best approach to start/print this.

1. Need to remove first column from the grid which is delete button.
2. If the list is long, the 2nd page should have the col.headers

Thank you.

(My reputation is 10 but still unable to add img.why?)

Comment: do you want to print content of your data grid view?

Answer (score 0):

I previously write a class for Print data grid view content

Add this class to your project:[print data grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879880/show-data-in-report-rdlc/15880192#15880192)

Comment: Thank you irsog. Gonna take me a while to understand that.Working on it.

Comment: @Ruby:complete article is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView